# Entity Framework - Loading not initiating

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm creating fantasy football game and I'm using Entity Framework for the mapping of my database.

I'm getting a weird error when trying to get load my data. When query my teams, the League attribute is null. However if i query my leagues and then query my teams, the League attribute loads just fine. What is causing this issue and how do i fix it ?

P.S. I have tried removing virtual key work (for lazy loading) with no luck

Method

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetTeam(){
    var x = await context.Teams.ToListAsync(); 
    // var y = await context.Leagues.ToListAsync(); Leagues show up with this 
    return Json(x);
}
```

Models

```
public class League {
    public int LeagueID { get; set; }
    public string LeagueName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Team> Teams { get; set; }
    public League() {
        Teams = new List<Team>();
    }

}

public class Team{
    public int TeamID { get; set; }
    public string TeamName { get; set; }
    public int LeagueID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("LeagueID")]
    public virtual League League { get; set; }
    public Team() {}
}
```

Context

```
public class GameDbContext : DbContext{
    public GameDbContext(DbContextOptions<GameDbContext> options): base(options) {
    }
    public DbSet<League> Leagues { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder) {
        builder.Entity<League>().ToTable("Leagues");
        builder.Entity<Team>().ToTable("Teams");
    }
}
```

Debug

without Y

[image]

with Y

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you have tried removing the virtual keyword from your League property in Team class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
context.Teams.Include(t=>t.League).ToListAsync()
```

will get you the league all the time.
You'll have to add a  `using System.Data.Entity;` for that to work

Comment: Weird, why doesnt it load the League on its own ?

Comment: It is great that it does not. It avoids 1+N query problem with lazy loading.

Comment: Okay, so i want to attach Owner to my Team model, and i want the League and the Owner. Do i have to do two includes queries  or is there a way i can grab both in one query? Because as you just saw the ToListAsync, leaves null values.

Comment: Sorry to do this to do you Alex, but i got another question. I did add a Owner model and I added the two includes and the Owner shows up, but the values inside the Owner modle are all null. How do i work around this ?

Comment: Thanks alex, i figured it all out. Sorry to bug you

Comment: No problem at all